# banner rotator advertising with probability

Tags: php, ads, banner

I have banners advertising with number of views, like CPM system.
And for example :

```
i have 3 banner:
banner1 with 20.000 nr of views
banner2 with 10.000 nr of views
banner3 with 5.000 nr of views
```

and on my website the banner must to appear in this position (when the page is reloaded) :

banner1 banner2 banner1 banner2 banner3

if the number of views is higher then the probability of apparition is higher

how can i do this in php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your system is just... **stupid**. It perpetuates banners with lots of views while newly created banners with 0 or few views will never get a chance to be picked and thus *will never be actually seen*...

That being said, if you have an array that looks like this:

```
$banners = array
(
    'banner1' => 1,
    'banner2' => 2,
    'banner3' => 4,
    'banner4' => 8,
    'banner5' => 16,
);
```

You can use a function like this one to weightily pick one banner:

```
function Probability($data)
{
    if (is_array($data) === true) {
        $result = 0;
        $probability = mt_rand(1, array_sum($data));

        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $result += $value;

            if ($result >= $probability) {
                return $key;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

---

**Usage (test it [@ CodePad.org](http://codepad.org/bV6rstL4) or [@ IDEOne](http://www.ideone.com/6MjH5)):**

```
echo Probability($banners); // banner5
```

**Sample from 100 executions:**

```
Array
(
    [banner5] => 41
    [banner4] => 38
    [banner3] => 10
    [banner2] => 8
    [banner1] => 3
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a php way to do it

I'm imagining your array will look something like this...

```
$banners = array(

    array (
        'name' => 'banner1',
        'views' => 20
    ),
    array (
        'name' => 'banner2',
        'views' => 10
    ),
    array (
        'name' => 'banner3',
        'views' => 5
    )
);
```

This function basically loops through the banners and however many views a banner has, that many items of its array index are added to an array. Then a random one is chosen.  Items with more views have a better chance of being chosen.

```
function getWeightedRandom( $array ) {

    $universe_array = array();

    foreach ( $array as $k => $b ) {
        $universe += $b['views'];
        $universe_array = array_pad( $universe_array, $universe, $k );
}

    $rand = mt_rand( 0, count( $universe_array ) -1 );
    return $array[ $universe_array[ $rand ] ];

}


$r = getWeightedRandom($banners);
print_r($r);
```

A simple mysql option is:

```
select * from banners order by rand() * views desc limit 1
```

banners with more views will have a higher chance of being the top result

Comment: -1, That SQL query will always return the banner with the most views.